# Cannot excute query in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I try to use this tutorial: [Hello NHibernate](https://docs.google.com/Doc?docid=0AUP-rKyyUMKhZGczejdxeHZfOGMydHNqdGc0&hl=en&pli=1)

This is my config NHibernate file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" requirePermission="false" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate"/>
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <reflection-optimizer use="false"/>
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=dbTest; Trusted_Connection=true;</property>
      <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
      <mapping resource="TestNHibernate.user.hbm.xml" assembly="TestNHibernate"/>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration></configuration>
```

This is my mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                           assembly="TestNHibernate"
                           namespace="TestNHibernate">
  <class name="user" table="user">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name"  />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Class user:

```
 class user
    {

        public virtual int Id { get;set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is query code:

```
 Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.AddAssembly(typeof(user).Assembly);
                ISessionFactory sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();

                using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
                {                   
                    IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("from user as u");
                    IList<user> lst = query.List<user>();
                    foreach (var user in lst)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(user.Name);
                    }
                }
```

It's always show error:

> could not execute query [ select
>   user0_.Id as Id0_, user0_.Name as
>   Name0_ from user user0_ ] [SQL: select
>   user0_.Id as Id0_, user0_.Name as
>   Name0_ from user user0_]

I tried to insert, update but it's also show could not insert, update. Where is my problem?

Is there my mapping file?
Please give me advice! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

(1) In your mapping file, you should be enclosing the User table in square brackets, e.g. [User]. User is a reserved keyword in SQL Server (and most other SQL systems).

```
<class name="user" table="[user]">
```

(2) Whenever you get an exception in NHibernate, go into debug mode and look at the inner exceptions. Those usually provide hints as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If you use this code NHibernate will generate database schema and database script preventing case-sensitive or other errors.

```
 var conf = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
        conf.Configure();


        var export = new SchemaExport(conf);
        export.SetOutputFile(@"DatabaseScript.sql");
        export.Drop(true, true);
        export.Create(true, true);
```

I think also that "user" can be a reserved word ! Try:

```
IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("from [user] as u");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the table and column names in your mapping exactly match those defined in the DB schema. Case-sensitivity might be important as well depending on your SQL server configuration.